# Problem connecting to SVN repository

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, connection

Okay.  Just looking for some advice on how to debug a problem with connecting one machine to an SVN repository.

Here are the details:
(1) Two of our machines successfully connect to the SVN repository, but one machine does not.
(2) We are all using Windows XP and are using the TortoiseSVN client. 
(3) We all were able to connect from our own machines, but when we tried a third machine at multiple different times over multiple different days, that machine just would not connect.
(4) We were able to SSH via Putty into the machine, but SVN via Tortoise just would not connect.

What steps should I take to try to debug this connection problem?

Thanks for any insights and feedback.

Comment: This question might get a better resolution on serverfault.com even with the nature of SVN it sounds like a problem that group might be better at.

Comment: Step 1: I would update the question with more details.  Most importantly, what happens when you try to connect?  Any error messages, etc. will help.  Also, you will want to include details about your setup: Tortoise version, Subversion server version, are all the machines on the same LAN, etc.  The more data you provide the better.

Comment: What type of repository are you using? Is SVN mounted on Apache/WebDav? Please give us more details

Comment: Can you try a command line version of svn (like SilkSvn) and see if that can connect? Might help isolate which component is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was a common enough problem to be on the TortoiseSVN FAQ.  Here is what we found:

SVN+SSH: Connection closed unexpectedly

It has been reported that svn+ssh connections of the form svn+ssh://username@server.com which were previously working, stop working with TortoiseSVN 1.5. This seems to be related to plink, and occurs if you have a default hostname set in PuTTY.

If this is the case you can fix it by using regedit or regedt32 to clear HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/SimonTatham/Putty/Sessions/Default%20Settings/HostName.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out the mesg line in your .bashrc did work for me, so something like:

```
# mesg n
```